# Read Files from directory and echo certain line

Tags: php

I want to read all files from a directory but instead of displaying the first character i want to display a certain line, f.e. line 4.

```
    <?php
$directory = "content/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode("|", $contents);
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "$item[0]";
     }
  }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are your "lines" split into `$items`? Then you can echo `$items[3]` for the fourth line. Otherwise, explode by `"\n"` instead of `"|"` to get the lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file()` function. It reads files into an array, where every line will be an array member, to skip empty lines pass the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag paramater.

For more info consult the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
// `$items` is already an array
$items = explode("|", $contents);
// if you want first element of array just:
echo $item[0];
// if you want fourth element of array just:
echo $item[3];
// without `foreach`
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you show your file structure, please?
Basicaly you can use something like this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$items = explode("\r\n", $contents); //explode file content
foreach ($items as $item) {
   echo $item[3]; //echo your line
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i get the thrid Column of all lines of all files - instead of the thrid line of all files.